# Access DB says my datetime is wrong

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
"SELECT Dateipfad FROM Attribute WHERE FS = '290' AND Letztes_mal_bearbeitet <= '15.11.2011 11:06:58'"
```

The datetimeValue is from a datetimepicker

Comment: Use parameterized queries and you don't have to deal with the specific formatting required in the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a particular date type the date enclosed by hash marks. Try to use:

```
SELECT Dateipfad FROM Attribute WHERE FS = '290' AND Letztes_mal_bearbeitet <= #15/11/2011 11:06:58#;
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT Dateipfad FROM Attribute WHERE FS = '290' AND Letztes_mal_bearbeitet <= @date"
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, oConnection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", myDateTimePicker.Value);
//execute same way like you did before...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the . (dot) in the values with slash /

```
SELECT Dateipfad FROM Attribute WHERE FS = '290' AND Letztes_mal_bearbeitet <= '15/11/2011 11:06:58'
```

Answer (score 1):

add this while loading the form

```
datetimepicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    datetimepicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with LassV. Karlsen suggestion.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa160564(v=office.11).aspx